# Exporta Excel no escribe todos los datos

Tags: java, base-de-datos, excel

Tengo un proceso que me exporta la informacion de un Resultset hacia un archivo normal en excel que funciona bien con 500 a 600 registros, pero si pasan de esa cantidad de registros no me escribe toda la informacion, es decir omite muchos datos.

Aqui mi codigo para este proceso :

```
<%@page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"%>
<%@include file="../js/$GLOBAL.jsp"%>
<% 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Exporta.xls\"");
String StRem, StPlz,StFVence="";
StRem = request.getParameter("Rm");
StPlz = request.getParameter("Pl");
String StFIni = request.getParameter("fechaInicial");
String StFFin = request.getParameter("fechaFinal");
String StNCte = request.getParameter("cliente");
        String FechaCaptura = "", Nombre = "", CParentesco = "", Tag = "", Attribute1 = "", Identificacion = "", Comentarios = "",
                Num_Identificador = "", Num_Visitas = "",Puerta="",VisibleN="",Tipo="",Motivo="",FechaEntrega="",Clave="",CSituacion="",
                Motivocliente="";
 %>
 <table  style='font-size:14px;border:1px solid lightgray;border-spacing:6px;border-collapse:collapse;box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #ccc,0px 5px 5px #eee;'>
<thead>
        <tr bgcolor='lightgray' ALIGN='CENTER'>
                        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <%
    try{
            int r = 0;
            $_Query = "SELECT distinct R.CLIENTE_ID,r.remesa_id,R.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,R.OT,R.DESCRIPCION,to_char(R.FECHA,'dd-mm-yyyy') fecha, RL.CODIGO_QP,RL.CUENTA,RL.CODIGO,RL.DESTINATARIO,RL.CALLE_NUMERO,RL.COLONIA,RL.CIUDAD_MUNICIPIO,"
                + "COALESCE(RL.ESTADO,'') AS ESTADO,RL.CP,COALESCE(RL.TELEFONO,'') AS TELEFONO,COALESCE(RL.DIARIO_ID,0) AS DIARIO_ID,COALESCE(to_char(DLN.FECHA_CREA_DIARIO,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'') fsalida,COALESCE(to_char(DLN.FECHA_CIERRE_DIARIO,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'') frecibo,"
                + "PF.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || PF.LAST_NAME mensajero,LKE.MEANING estatus,substr(HP.PARTY_NAME,1,35) cte,bl.ordered_item nprod,IT.DESCRIPTION prod,lk.attribute1 nplaza,LK.MEANING plaza,case when lk.description = '(L)' then 'Local' "
                + " when lk.description = '(F)' then 'Foraneo' end as agrupacion,bl.attribute13,coalesce(to_char(gps.fecha,'dd-mm-yyyy'),' ') as escaneo,gps.latitud||' '||gps.longitud as datogps,CASE WHEN ORIGEN !=4 THEN 'NO' WHEN ORIGEN = 4 THEN 'SI' END AS SINERGIA  "
                + "from XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_TBL r inner join XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_CORTE_HD_TBL rc on R.REMESA_ID = RC.REMESA_ID inner join XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_CORTE_LN_TBL rl "
                + "on RC.CORTE_ID = RL.CORTE_ID left join XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_HD_TBL dln on RL.DIARIO_ID = DLN.DIARIO_ID "
                + " left join XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_LN_TBL diario on diario.diario_id= RL.DIARIO_ID   "
                + " left join XXQP.XXQP_GPS_TBL gps on gps.gps_id = diario.gps_id inner join AR.HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS hz on r.cliente_id = HZ.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID inner join AR.HZ_PARTIES hp on HZ.PARTY_ID = HP.PARTY_ID "
                + "inner join APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL it on (R.PRODUCTO_ID=it.inventory_item_id and R.ALMACEN_ID=it.organization_id and it.language='ESA') "
                + "inner join apps.oe_blanket_lines_all bl on IT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = BL.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID and bl.CONTEXT = 'Operaciones' "
                + "inner join APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES lk on (LK.LOOKUP_TYPE='XXQP_PLAZAS' and LK.LANGUAGE='ESA' and RC.PLAZA_ID = LK.LOOKUP_CODE) "
                + "inner join APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES lkE on (LKE.LOOKUP_TYPE='XXQPN_ESTATUS_FLUJO_GRAL' and LKE.LANGUAGE='ESA' and RL.ESTATUS_ID = LKE.LOOKUP_CODE) "
                + " left join per_assignments_f pa "
                + "on DLN.COLABORADOR_ID = PA.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER left join APPS.PER_PEOPLE_F pf on PA.PERSON_ID = PF.PERSON_ID WHERE 1=1";

                if(!StRem.equals("")){
                     $_Query = $_Query + " and r.remesa_id in ("+StRem+")";
                }
                if(StRem.equals("")){
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and R.FECHA >=TO_DATE('" + StFIni + " 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')"
                    + "and R.FECHA <= TO_DATE('" + StFFin + " 23:59:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') and rl.estatus!='CANCELADO'";
                    if(!StNCte.equals("")){
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and hz.account_number='"+StNCte+"'";
                    }
                }
                if (!StPlz.equals("0"))
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and LK.ATTRIBUTE1='"+StPlz+"'";
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and rl.estatus!='CANCELADO' order by r.remesa_id";
            rs1 = Gdr.consultar($_Query, 2);
            System.out.println("Query >>" + $_Query);
            while (rs1.next()) {
            if (r == 0) {%>
        <tr bgcolor='white' ALIGN='CENTER'>
        <%
            r = 1;
        } else {
            r = 0;
        %>
        <tr bgcolor='#E6E6E6' ALIGN='CENTER'>
        <%                                  }%>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("cliente_id")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("remesa_id")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("account_number")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("ot")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("descripcion")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("fecha")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("codigo_qp")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("cuenta")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("codigo")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("destinatario")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("calle_numero")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("colonia")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("ciudad_municipio")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("estado")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("cp")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("telefono")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("diario_id")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("fsalida")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("frecibo")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("mensajero")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("estatus")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("cte")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("nprod")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString("prod")%></td>              
        </tr>
            <%    }
                Gdr.cerrar();
            %>
                </tbody>
</table>      
        <%
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                    }%>                       
</tbody>
</table>
```

Y como les comento, después de 600 filas empieza a mal funcionar.

Comment: Creo que el problema es tener todo ese contenido en HTML. Es una **muy mala práctica** usar HTML para generar tus archivos word, excel, etc. Deberías usar una librería como Apache POI que permite procesar esta información sin problemas. Con POI puedes generar archivos con miles de líneas sin problemas, y luego ofrecer la descarga del archivo generado.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tendras alguna liga de ejemplo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya he logrado solucionarlo, de esta manera la informacion se descaraga al 100%, usando apache poi para hacer el Export de los datos

```
    <%
    try{
        try {
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.100:1523:prod", "apps", "apps");
Connection con2= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.249:1521:easy","ebsqp","ebsqp");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
Statement stSegundo = con.createStatement();
Statement stTercero = con2.createStatement();
//ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(
    $_Query ="SELECT distinct R.CLIENTE_ID,r.remesa_id,"
        + " R.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,R.OT,R.DESCRIPCION,to_char(R.FECHA,'dd-mm-yyyy') fecha, RL.CODIGO_QP,RL.CUENTA,RL.CODIGO,RL.DESTINATARIO,RL.CALLE_NUMERO,RL.COLONIA,RL.CIUDAD_MUNICIPIO,"
        + " COALESCE(RL.ESTADO,' ') AS ESTADO,RL.CP,COALESCE(RL.TELEFONO,' ') AS TELEFONO,COALESCE(RL.DIARIO_ID,0) AS DIARIO_ID,COALESCE(to_char(DLN.FECHA_CREA_DIARIO,'dd-mm-yyyy'),' ') fsalida,COALESCE(to_char(DLN.FECHA_CIERRE_DIARIO,'dd-mm-yyyy'),' ') frecibo,"
        + " PF.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || PF.LAST_NAME mensajero,LKE.MEANING estatus,substr(HP.PARTY_NAME,1,35) cte,bl.ordered_item nprod,IT.DESCRIPTION prod,lk.attribute1 nplaza,LK.MEANING plaza,case when lk.description = '(L)' then 'Local' "
        + "  when lk.description = '(F)' then 'Foraneo' end as agrupacion,bl.attribute13,coalesce(to_char(gps.fecha,'dd-mm-yyyy'),' ') as escaneo,gps.latitud||' '||gps.longitud as datogps,CASE WHEN ORIGEN !=4 THEN 'NO' WHEN ORIGEN = 4 THEN 'SI' END AS SINERGIA " 
        + " from XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_TBL r inner join XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_CORTE_HD_TBL rc on R.REMESA_ID = RC.REMESA_ID inner join XXQP.XXQP_REMESA_CORTE_LN_TBL rl "
        + " on RC.CORTE_ID = RL.CORTE_ID left join XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_HD_TBL dln on RL.DIARIO_ID = DLN.DIARIO_ID "
        + "  left join XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_LN_TBL diario on diario.diario_id= RL.DIARIO_ID   "
        + "  left join XXQP.XXQP_GPS_TBL gps on gps.gps_id = diario.gps_id inner join AR.HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS hz on r.cliente_id = HZ.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID "
        + "  inner join AR.HZ_PARTIES hp on HZ.PARTY_ID = HP.PARTY_ID "
        + " inner join APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL it on (R.PRODUCTO_ID=it.inventory_item_id and R.ALMACEN_ID=it.organization_id and it.language='ESA') "
        + " inner join apps.oe_blanket_lines_all bl on IT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = BL.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID and bl.CONTEXT = 'Operaciones' "
        + " inner join APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES lk on (LK.LOOKUP_TYPE='XXQP_PLAZAS' and LK.LANGUAGE='ESA' and RC.PLAZA_ID = LK.LOOKUP_CODE) "
        + " inner join APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES lkE on (LKE.LOOKUP_TYPE='XXQPN_ESTATUS_FLUJO_GRAL' and LKE.LANGUAGE='ESA' and RL.ESTATUS_ID = LKE.LOOKUP_CODE) "
        + "  left join per_assignments_f pa "
        + " on DLN.COLABORADOR_ID = PA.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER left join APPS.PER_PEOPLE_F pf on PA.PERSON_ID = PF.PERSON_ID WHERE 1=1 ";

        if(!StRem.equals("")){
            $_Query = $_Query + " and r.remesa_id in ("+StRem+")";
        }
        if(StRem.equals("")){
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and R.FECHA >=TO_DATE('" + StFIni + " 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')"
                    + "and R.FECHA <= TO_DATE('" + StFFin + " 23:59:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') and rl.estatus!='CANCELADO'";
                    if(!StNCte.equals("")){
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and hz.account_number='"+StNCte+"'";
                    }


                }
         if (!StPlz.equals("0"))
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and LK.ATTRIBUTE1='"+StPlz+"'";
                    $_Query = $_Query + " and rl.estatus!='CANCELADO' order by r.remesa_id";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery($_Query);



        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Exporta");
        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

        rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("REMESA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("CODIGO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("CUENTA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("CODIGOCLIENTE");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("NOMBRE");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("CALLE");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue("COLONIA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue("MUNICIPIO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue("ESTADO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue("CP");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue("TELEFONO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 11).setCellValue("NCLIENTE");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 12).setCellValue("CLIENTE");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 13).setCellValue("ESTATUS");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 14).setCellValue("NMENSAJERIA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 15).setCellValue("AGRUPACION");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 16).setCellValue("FECHA ENTREGA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 17).setCellValue("F.RECIBO_DIARIO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 18).setCellValue("TIPO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 19).setCellValue("CLAVE");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 20).setCellValue("C SITUACION");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 21).setCellValue("FECHA CAPTURA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 22).setCellValue("NUM_VISITAS");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 23).setCellValue("RECIBIO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 24).setCellValue("IDENTIFICACION");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 25).setCellValue("NUM. IDENTIFICACION");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 26).setCellValue("PARENTESCO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 27).setCellValue("COMENTARIOS");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 28).setCellValue("ESCANEO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 29).setCellValue("DATO GPS");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 30).setCellValue("OT");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 31).setCellValue("DESCRIPCION");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 32).setCellValue("NPRODUCTO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 33).setCellValue("PRODUCTO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 34).setCellValue("F.LLEGADA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 35).setCellValue("FECHA VENCIMIENTO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 36).setCellValue("MOTIVO CTE");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 37).setCellValue("SINERGIA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 38).setCellValue("DIARIO");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 39).setCellValue("F.SALIDA");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 40).setCellValue("MENSAJERO");


int i = 1;
while (rs.next()){

    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
    row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("remesa_id"));
    row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("codigo_qp"));
    row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("cuenta"));
    row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString("codigo"));
    row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("destinatario"));
    row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getString("calle_numero"));
    row.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(rs.getString("colonia"));
    row.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(rs.getString("ciudad_municipio"));
    row.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue(rs.getString("estado"));
    row.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue(rs.getString("cp"));
    row.createCell((short) 10).setCellValue(rs.getString("telefono"));
    row.createCell((short) 11).setCellValue(rs.getString("account_number"));
    row.createCell((short) 12).setCellValue(rs.getString("cte"));
    row.createCell((short) 13).setCellValue(rs.getString("estatus"));
    row.createCell((short) 14).setCellValue(rs.getString("nplaza"));
    row.createCell((short) 15).setCellValue(rs.getString("agrupacion"));
    row.createCell((short) 16).setCellValue(FechaEntrega);
    row.createCell((short) 17).setCellValue(rs.getString("fsalida"));
    row.createCell((short) 18).setCellValue(Tipo);
    row.createCell((short) 19).setCellValue(Clave);
    row.createCell((short) 20).setCellValue(CSituacion);
    row.createCell((short) 21).setCellValue(FechaCaptura);
    row.createCell((short) 22).setCellValue(Num_Visitas);
    row.createCell((short) 23).setCellValue(Nombre);
    row.createCell((short) 24).setCellValue(Identificacion);
    row.createCell((short) 25).setCellValue(Num_Identificador);
    row.createCell((short) 26).setCellValue(CParentesco);
    row.createCell((short) 27).setCellValue(Comentarios);
    row.createCell((short) 28).setCellValue(rs.getString("escaneo"));
    row.createCell((short) 29).setCellValue(rs.getString("datogps"));
    row.createCell((short) 30).setCellValue(rs.getString("ot"));
    row.createCell((short) 31).setCellValue(rs.getString("descripcion"));
    row.createCell((short) 32).setCellValue(rs.getString("nprod"));
    row.createCell((short) 33).setCellValue(rs.getString("prod"));
    row.createCell((short) 34).setCellValue(rs.getString("fecha"));
    row.createCell((short) 35).setCellValue(StFVence);
    row.createCell((short) 36).setCellValue(Motivocliente);
    row.createCell((short) 37).setCellValue(rs.getString("SINERGIA"));
    row.createCell((short) 38).setCellValue(rs.getString("diario_id"));
    row.createCell((short) 39).setCellValue(rs.getString("frecibo"));
    row.createCell((short) 40).setCellValue(rs.getString("mensajero"));
    i++;
}

String yemi = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resource.qp").getString("rutaServerAlterna");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(yemi+"Exporta.xls");
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

String nombre ="Exporta.xls";
String yemi = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resource.qp").getString("rutaServerAlterna");
java.io.FileInputStream archivo = new java.io.FileInputStream(yemi+nombre);

int longitud = archivo.available();
byte [] datos = new byte [longitud];
archivo.read(datos);
archivo.close();

response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+"Exporta.xls");
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setContentLength(longitud);
response.getOutputStream().write(datos);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();

            %>

        <%
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }%>
```

Saludos y gracias por su apoyo.